# Force call __attribute__((const)) function

Tags: c

A library I'm using provides a const function that does some initialization the first time it is called:

`foo_t get_foo(void) __attribute__((const));`

I need to call `get_foo` before some other tasks that depend on the initialization it does. How can I do this reliably?

The compiler can and will eliminate a simple `get_foo();` call.

A solution I thought out that seems to work is assigning the result to a dummy volatile variable:

`volatile foo_t dummy = get_foo();`

First, is the behavior of that well-defined?

Second, is there a way to force-call a const function without the dummy variable?

Comment: Please provide more (and structured) information what your problem is. As given your question is unclear.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "well-defined", but clearly when you're dealing with code that uses compiler-specific extensions, it's not well-defined as far as as standard C is concerned. Do you mean "will this work with my compiler?" You should be able to answer that better than the rest of us, since you know which compiler it is that you're using.

Comment: The compiler is GCC, I can hardly provide any more specifics. I tried looking in the GCC documentation to find answers, but failed. I thought maybe someone had some experience with this already.

Comment: If the function has side-effects, it shall not be `const` attributed. Note that e.g. allocating memory **is** a side-effect. provide a [mcve].

Comment: With GCC, [`__attribute__((const))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) is a promise to the compiler that the function has no side effects. If the function *does* have side effects, ideally, get the developers responsible for that library you're using to fix their code... You should just be able to remove the attribute from the header yourself for now.

Comment: @Olaf I know that, but since it came from a library, I can't really do much about it.

Comment: After a bit more digging, I found that this has already been reported to the library developers in 2001 (!). The upside is that there is another way to do it that I did not know about. For your reference: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64994